# Sometimes my kitten doesn't eat from his plate

Tags: cats, behavior, diet

This happens around 20-25% of the time I feed my kitten.

The kitten asks me for food. I put the food in the plate & keep it at his usual eating place. He will smell it and then walk away disdainfully. 
However,if I take small bite size portions in my hand and feed him - he will eat it - I have to feed him around 3-4 bites by hand & then he will move to the plate and start eating it. Alternately, if instead of feeding him by hand, if I take a piece and put it on the floor, he will eat it. Again if he eats around 3-4 pieces from the floor, he will move to the plate and start eating off the plate.

My kitten is around 8-9 months old, male, neutered.

What can be the reason for this? And what's the solution?

Comment: Perhaps your cat dislikes the smell of the dishwashing liquid or soaps you use to wash the plate.

Comment: Or maybe the pieces on the plate are too large for his liking

Comment: @StigTore - no they are very small pieces and it's the same thing he eats once he goes to the plate. Also this is just 1 out of 4 times. The remaining 3 times he eats just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever fed him wet food? when my cat was a kitten we fed him wet food off a paper plate for awhile,Maybe the cat doesn't like the 'texture' of the plate as when he licks it  may not be to his liking. Anyway if you haven't fed him wet food before maybe try that and try paper plates ( or just a different bowl/plate)

Comment: I feed him very less dry food.